# Ubuntu PATH not persisting after reboot despite editing bashrc and profile

Tags: linux, ubuntu, path

I have 3 exports (1 to path):

```
export GOPATH=$HOME/go
export GOBIN=$GOPATH/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$GOBIN:/usr/local/go/bin
```

Typing this in terminal works only for the current session. If I type it in .bashrc and .profile, it works only as long as I run

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

in a new session. How can I avoid having to run the source command in every session?

Comment: Check if you have .zshrc file. If has it put your path in this file

Answer (score 0):

This supposes that your default shell is in fact Bash, which is likely, but not certain.

Bash reads `~/.profile` automatically only in an interactive login shell, and *only if there is no `~/.bash_profile`*.  It is not unusual for Linux distributions to ensure that users have a minimal `.bash_profile` by default.

Bash reads `~/.bashrc` automatically only in interactive *non*-login shells.

Taken together, there's a good chance that neither of those is being read automatically in the shell opened in a terminal window, or the one serving (say) an ssh session.  You should instead **put your commands in `~/.bash_profile`**.  Alternatively, put them in `~/.bashrc`, and tell `~/.bash_profile` to perform the `source ~/.bashrc`.

Comment: I am accessing via an SSH session, so that could be the case. I will check it out shortly. EDIT: still nothing. echo $SHELL returns bash.

Comment: @SHCMostWanted, it would be worthwhile, then, to check what your login shell actually is, and to find out how it is being invoked.  Do you administer this machine yourself?  If not, then this would be a question better taken up with your sysadmin.